# Set<? extends MyClass> should be disallowed as an object declaration

Tags: java, generics, extends

The code

```
Set<? extends MyClass> mySet = new HashSet<>();
mySet.add(new MyClass());
```

produces an error message. The reason is that the compiler doesn't know the type of *mySet.* All it knows is that the type of *mySet* is *Set<SomeType>* where *SomeType* is a subtype of *MyType.*  Since the compiler doesn't know which type  *Set<? **extends** MyClass>* refers to the only thing it will allow to be inserted into *Sets* of that type is **null.**

Since this is very confusing and since there is minimal use for sets whose only possible element is **null**, it would make more sense to disallow the use of *<? **extends** SomeClass>* when declaring objects, i.e., as in the example above. This form should be used *only* for declaring abstractions (such as parameters or generic classes or methods) that are going to be made concrete later.

I realize this isn't a question, but I wonder what the reaction is to the idea.

Comment: The add() method does not work (allows only nulls), but other methods, such as get() work.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I buy it.  I can imagine cases where

```
Set<? extends MyClass> mySet = getOtherSet();
```

where `getOtherSet`'s return type might be `Set<MySubClass>`, or even `Set<? extends MyClass>`.  That is, and should be, a legitimate use of generics.

The only way to distinguish the above legitimate use from the problematic case you describe is exactly what Java already does -- it produces an error message at compile time.

Comment: Yes and no. I understand your point, but ... . If the return type of `getOtherSet` were `Set<MySubClass>` why not use that for `mySet`? (We are not declaring a parameter in an API; we are declaring a variable in code that we are writing. We know what we are calling and what their return types are.) Also, I can't see why the return type of `getOtherSet` would be `Set<? extends MyClass>` unless a variable were declared that way, which I want to prohibit. So although I see  your point, I would like to see the example expanded a bit more to be convinced.  (By the way, I love your work in Guava.)

Comment: Here's one example. Suppose I have a method `myMethod(<? extends myType> myParam)` and I want to assign `myParam` to an instance variable. That instance variable must be of type `<? extends myType>`.  So I guess my proposed prohibition is too broad.

Comment: So now I would suggest that the only variables to be declared `<? extends MyType>` should be downstream from a parameter of that type.

Comment: And here's what might originate a need for `<? extends MyType>`. What Guava calls a `MultiSet<AType, ? extends AnotherType>` is like this: `Map<AType, Set<? extends AnotherType>>`. I found it convenient to declare one of those.

Comment: `<? extends AnotherType> is a general way of expressing some unknown constant type.  If I receive a `<? extends MyType>`, then the only thing I can do is treat it as a `MyType`.  The only thing you can do with a `Set<? extends AnotherType>` is to treat it as a `Set` that you can't add things to, but you can take `AnotherType` values out of -- unless you're willing to do unsafe casts of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

`Set<? extends MyClass>` is a perfectly useful type in general. You can have a method argument  that is `Set<? extends MyClass>`, that allows you to call it with `Set<OneClass>` or `Set<AnotherClass>`. If all the method needs to do is get `MyClass` elements out of it, it's fine. Or, you can have a statement like

```
Set<? extends MyClass> mySet = someObject.someMethod();
```

where the method could return sets of different types (some instances might return `Set<OneClass>`, while others might return `Set<AnotherClass>`), and all you need to do with it now is get `MyClass` things out of it.

The example you are showing specifically deals with initializing `Set<? extends MyClass>` with a new empty set. I agree that this case is not that useful. However, if we need to make a rule to disallow this case, it would have to make assigning an object creation expression different from assigning other expressions (like a method call), even if they are equivalent (the method call could also be just returning a new empty set). I think that it would be unreasonable to explicitly exclude such a case when it does not do any harm. You could similarly argue that being able to create arrays of length 0 is a pretty useless, and should be disallowed; however, it makes the language more general to be able to handle edge cases.